# ViewHolder в списке с разными View

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть список с подкатегориями, который по определенным причинам пришлось сделать с помощью ListView, вместо ExpandableListView. Мне нужно реализовать паттерн `ViewHolder` в адаптере для двух типов элементов - категории и подкатегории. Я попробовал несколько вариантов, но приложение выкидывало ошибку. Как правильно это сделать?

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
class JuzAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    List<Juz> data = new ArrayList<>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public JuzAdapter(List<Juz> data){
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (data.get(position).isSection){
            Juz juz = data.get(position);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_ajza_header, null);
            TextView juzId_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.juz_id);
            TextView juzText_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.juz_text);
            juzId_tv.setText(String.valueOf(juz.juzId));
            juzText_tv.setText(juz.text);
        }else {
            Rub rub = (Rub) data.get(position);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_ajza_child, null);
            TextView hizbIndicator_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hizb_indicator);
            ImageView hizbIndicator_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hizb_indicator_secondary);
            TextView rubText_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rub_text);
            TextView ayahSource_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ayah_source);
            hizbIndicator_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rub.hizbId));
            rubText_tv.setText(rub.text);
            ayahSource_tv.setText(String.format("(%s:%s)", rub.surahId,rub.ayahId));
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (data.get(position).isSection){
            return 0;
        }else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Без указания того, какая ошибка и на какой строке (не номер, а конкретный код на строке) вам помочь сложно - все экстрасенсы в отпуске.

Comment: В представленном коде не наблюдается никаких попыток использования ViewHolder. Как вы думаете вам можно помочь, если вы не представили воспроизводимый пример вашей проблемы. Вы хотите, чтобы к представленному вами коду кто то прикрутил ViewHolder? - так и пишите тогда в вопросе, зачем писать о собственных неудачных попытках, если их результатов нет в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Определите метод getViewTypeCount() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount()

Вместо `if (data.get(position).isSection){}` для определения типа используйте метод `int getItemViewType(int position)`

И нужно будет для каждого типа элемента определить свой ViewHolder